# BigCommerce Category Specific Featured Products

Tags: php, e-commerce

I want to display a featured product in a category (product list) page, but the featured product needs to be under that category.

I searched a lot but could not find any answer. So, if any of you can let me know whether this is doable and how, it would highly be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read this support link?

https://support.bigcommerce.com/questions/1093/How+do+I+create+a+custom+category+template%3F

I think it might help you.